# Explicit throughput limiting on part of an akka stream

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have a flow in our system which reads some elements from SQS (using alpakka) and does some preporcessing (~ 10 stages, normally < 1 minute in total). Then, the prepared element is sent to the main processing (single stage, taking a few minutes). The whole thing runs on AWS/K8S and we’d like to scale out when the SQS queue grows above a certain threshold. The issue is, the SQS queue takes a long time to blow up, since there are a lot of elements “idling” in-process, having done their preprocessing but waiting for the main thing.

We can’t externalize the preprocessing stuff to a separate queue since their outcome can’t survive a de/serialization roundtrip. Also, this service and the “main” processor are deeply coupled (this service runs as main’s sidecar) and can’t be scaled independently.

The preprocessing stages are technically `.mapAsyncUnordered`, but the whole thing is already very slim (stream stages and SQS batches/buffers).

We tried lowering the interstage buffer (akka.stream.materializer.max-input-buffer-size), but that only gives some indirect benefit, no direct control (and is too internal to be mucking with, for my taste anyway).

I tried implementing a “gate” wrapper which would limit the amount of elements allowed inside some arbitrary `Flow`, looking something like:

```
class LimitingGate[T, U](originalFlow: Flow[T, U], maxInFlight: Int) {
  private def in: InputGate[T] = ???
  private def out: OutputGate[U] = ???

  def gatedFlow: Flow[T, U, NotUsed] = Flow[T].via(in).via(originalFlow).via(out)
}
```

And using callbacks between the in/out gates for throttling.

The implementation partially works (stream termination is giving me a hard time), but it feels like the wrong way to go about achieving the actual goal.

Any ideas / comments / enlightening questions are appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: One hacky(?), but entirely within the stream DSL, way to bound the total number of elements in flight in the flow that would work regardless of the number of stages/async boundaries in the flow, would be to zip a `Source.actorRef` (prematerialization helps) with the SQS source.  The zip ensures that a message only gets passed downstream for each message sent to the `actorRef`, so you'd send a message to the `actorRef` whenever the long processing is finished.

Comment: Out of interest, are there any `async`s (not `mapAsync` or `mapAsyncUnordered`) in your code, because the materializer input buffer should only matter for async boundaries (there's probably one in the SQS source).

Comment: @LeviRamsey , there are no `.async` boundaries explicitly in our code. Didn't look through all of alpakka code, but indeed there probably is at least one there

Can you explain the "zip with `Source.actorRef`" comment? Not sure I understand...

Thanks!

Comment: If you prematerialize a `Source.actorRef`, you get an `ActorRef` that you can send messages to from the rest of the stream and have those messages go into the stream.  So if you have a zip stage combining the SQS source with the prematerialized actor source, elements will get passed through only if the actor source has emitted an element.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines (I'm only compiling it in my head):

```
def inflightLimit[A, B, M](n: Int, source: Source[T, M])(businessFlow: Flow[T, B, _])(implicit materializer: Materializer): Source[B, M] = {
  require(n > 0)  // alternatively, could just result in a Source.empty...
  val actorSource = Source.actorRef[Unit](
    completionMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
    failureMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
    bufferSize = 2 * n,
    overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropHead  // shouldn't matter, but if the buffer fills, the effective limit will be reduced
  )
  val (flowControl, unitSource) = actorSource.preMaterialize()

  source.statefulMapConcat { () =>
    var firstElem: Boolean = true
    { a =>
      if (firstElem) {
        (0 until n).foreach(_ => flowControl.tell(()))  // prime the pump on stream materialization
        firstElem = false
      }
      List(a)
    }}
    .zip(unitSource)
    .map(_._1)
    .via(businessFlow)
    .wireTap { _ => flowControl.tell(()) }  // wireTap is Akka Streams 2.6, but can be easily replaced by a map stage which sends () to flowControl and passes through the input
 }
```

Basically:

- `actorSource` will emit a `Unit` (`()`, i.e. meaningless) element for every `()` it receives
- `statefulMapConcat` will cause `n` messages to be sent to the `actorSource` only when the stream first starts (thus allowing `n` elements from the source through)
- `zip` will pass on a pair of the input from `source` and a `()` only when `actorSource` and `source` both have an element available
- for every element which exits `businessFlow`, a message will be sent to the `actorSource`, which will allow another element from the source through

Some things to note:

- this will not in any way limit buffering within `source`
- `businessFlow` cannot drop elements: after `n` elements are dropped the stream will no longer process elements but won't fail; if dropping elements is required, you may be able to inline `businessFlow` and have the stages which drop elements send a message to `flowControl` when they drop an element; there are other things to address this which you can do as well